# how do I access image height & width, image resolution, file size using adobe flash builder 4.6?

Tags: image, file, air, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

My desktop AIR app has an area for drag n drop images.

The images are assumed to be from the Local Disk where the app is running on.

The drag n dropped images will be zipped up into a zip file and then uploaded to a server.

The images are usually first stored into an ArrayCollection.

I want to iteratively go through each file and determine the following.

**Height & Width (in pixels), Resolutions(in dpi)**

Should any of the files fail to meet some predetermined criteria, the code should prompt an error message and stop proceeding with the zip.

Should the files be zipped into a zip file, I will store the new zipped file inside the applicationStorageDirectory awaiting upload.

**After which I want to determine the size of this newly generated zip file in mB**

How do I access the above 4 statistics using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6?

Comment: I am unable to add flash-builder4.6 tag. Someone please help to create it.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse out the header information for [JPGs](http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/getting-jpg-dimensions-with-as3-without-loading-the-entire-file/) and [PNGs](http://richardjdare.com/blog/2010/10/getting-the-size-of-a-png-without-loading-it/) (including height, width, and, for some JPGs, DPI) without loading the whole file.  I haven't fully evaluated the approaches in the links, but the general approach of using a `FileStream` to get the first few bytes and then parsing those as a header will work for these (and many other) formats.

Once you've created the zip file, [`FileReference.size`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#size) will give you the file size.  (`File` inherits this property).